# Setting Focus from within the OnLostFocus event c# silverlight component one masked textbox

Tags: c#, silverlight, componentone

I am trying to perform some custom validation inside the c1 masked textbox and the validation has to occur OnLostFocus(). The problem is, when im calling Focus() from within OnLostFocus(), its causing the control to lose/gain focus again which is infinite looping. Any help/suggestions would be great!

thanks in advance!!!

below is basically the code behind what I have:

```
    protected override void OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (!CheckAndRunValidator())
        {
            Focus();
            SelectAll();

            return;
        }

        base.OnLostFocus(e);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => Focus() );
```

If that does not work try using a `DispatcherTimer` with a short `Interval` and do the focus int the `Tick` event.

Comment: if (!CheckAndRunValidator())
            {
                var dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer {Interval = new TimeSpan(300)};

                dispatcherTimer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => Focus());
                    dispatcherTimer.Stop();
                };

                dispatcherTimer.Start();
            }